# VM has no Internet access

Tags: wifi, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I am using Windows 8.1 in my laptop and I have created a Windows Server 2012 R2 Virtual Machine using Hyper-V.

I have tried to give the VM Internet access. I followed [this](https://superuser.com/questions/469806/windows-8-hyper-v-how-to-give-vm-internet-access) thread, but my VM still has no Internet access.

I can see the Wi-Fi is bridged and the VM got an IP-address, and both my laptop and VM has same default gateway.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't sound like an issue with the HyperV setup. But instead just sounds like you aren't aware of the Enhanced Security Configuration placed on Internet Explorer by default in a server OS.

Check this out the following blog post on how to remove them.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/chenley/2011/03/10/how-to-turn-off-internet-explorer-enhanced-security-configuration/

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem. it was proxy settings issue.